# hwo to use pcl to achieve that discretizing the 3D point cloud into a 2D grid over the xy plane, not use the voxelgrid?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to project the 3D point cloud into a 2D grid over the xy plane, each grid cell size is 20cm*20cm, how to achieve it effectively?

NOT use VoxelGrid method, because I want to retain every point and deal with them in the next step(Gaussian kernel every column and use EM to deal with each grid)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749230/6812182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can achieve what you want with `OctreePointCloudPointVector` class.

Here is an example how to use the class:

```
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/octree/octree_pointcloud_pointvector.h>

using Cloud    = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>;
using CloudPtr = Cloud::Ptr;

using OctreeT = pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudPointVector<pcl::PointXYZ>;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
        return 1;

    // load cloud
    CloudPtr cloud(new Cloud);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile(argv[1], *cloud);

    CloudPtr cloud_projected(new Cloud(*cloud));
    // project to XY plane
    for(auto& pt : *cloud_projected)
        pt.z = 0.0f;

    // create octree, set resolution to 20cm
    OctreeT octree(0.2);
    octree.setInputCloud(cloud_projected);
    octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();

    // we gonna store the indices of the octree leafs here
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> indices_vec;
    indices_vec.reserve(octree.getLeafCount());

    // traverse the octree leafs and store the indices
    const auto it_end = octree.leaf_depth_end();
    for(auto it = octree.leaf_depth_begin(); it != it_end; ++it)
    {
        auto leaf = it.getLeafContainer();
        std::vector<int> indices; 
        leaf.getPointIndices(indices);
        indices_vec.push_back(indices);
    }

    // save leafs to file
    int cnt = 0;
    for(const auto indices : indices_vec)
    {
        Cloud leaf(*cloud, indices);
        pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary("leaf_" + std::to_string(cnt++) + ".pcd", leaf);
    }
}
```

You can see the output by calling `pcl_viewer`:

> pcl_viewer leaf_*.pcd

See sample output[image: sample output]

Comment: hi, serkan. I run the code, but I was confused that I cannot find the final result files(the name of leaf_number)when i use visual studio.

Comment: The files will be written to the path, where VS is running the program from. You can always change the path to an absolute path in `pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud with the following code:

```py
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud

cloud = PyntCloud.from_file("some_cloud.ply")
# 0.2 asumming your point cloud units are meters
voxelgrid_id = cloud.add_structure("voxelgrid", size_x=0.2, size_y=0.2)

voxelgrid = cloud.structures[voxelgrid_id]
```

You can learn more about VoxelGrid here:

https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/examples/%5Bstructures%5D%20VoxelGrid.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with *2D grid over the xy plane*? Do you still want the z value to be the original value, or do you want to project the point cloud to the XY plane first?

### Keep Z value

If you want to keep the Z values, just set the **leaf size** for **Z** of `VoxelGrid` to infinite (or a very large number).

```
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
sor.setInputCloud (cloud);
sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 100000.0f);
sor.filter (*cloud_filtered);
```

### Project Cloud to XY plane first

Project a cloud to the **XY plane** is nothing else than setting the **Z value** for each point to **0**.

```
for(auto& pt : cloud)
    pt.z = 0.0f;
```

Now you can do normal `VoxelGrid` on the projected point cloud.

Comment: from my understanding, VoxelGrid is a method to achieve down-sampling, which means each output point from the input grid.    I want to project the original pointcloud to xy plane and rasterize it, each grid size is 20cm*20cm, and retain every point in the point cloud, not down-sample

Comment: Ok I see. In that case, I would recommend using [OctreePointCloudPointVector](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_point_cloud_point_vector.html). 
Project your input point cloud to the XY plane first, use that projected point cloud as input for the Octree.
Afterwards, you will have the indices of the points from the input point cloud in each of the voxels.

Comment: yeah, I actually achieve the projection to xy plane,
but I am confused by the rasterize.
my projection method is
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients());
 coefficients->values.resize(4);
 coefficients->values[0] = 0;
 coefficients->values[1] = 0;
 coefficients->values[2] = 1;
 coefficients->values[3] = 0;

Comment: thank you for your reply, I actually search the Octree method, I am confused by something. The first thing is that whether the voxel by Octree is empty inside but just represent like a pixel on 2D plane. The second problem is that If I want know the disribution inside grid, what should I do?

Comment: @WanEthan I am gonna show you how to achieve what you want in a separate answer.