# Matching Pixel data and Point Cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have to organize a point cloud data from 1D to 2D. 
I already have a 1D point cloud data which holds the data only for pixels(called, valid pixels) with intensity of 255. 
So I have to organize the point cloud according to the image. 
I am having problems accessing the 2D point cloud. I don't know how to do it.

```
// Here the data from in_ThreeD_cloud which is of type tDistanceData is converted to tVec3f
const rrlib::math::tVec3f *points = reinterpret_cast<const rrlib::math::tVec3f*>(in_ThreeD_cloud->DataPtr());

int num_valid_points = 0;

// An object to class PointCloud is created
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> cloud; 

// Image data from the camera is accessed as Matrix
cv::Mat image  = rrlib::coviroa::AccessImageAsMat(in_img->at(0));

// Dimensions of the point cloud is sent as parameters to overloaded constuctor
cloud(image.cols, image.rows); 

// The point cloud is expected to store the vector3f data in a 2D format
for(int i = 0; i <= image.rows; ++i)
for(int j = 0; j <= image.cols; ++j)
{
     if( image.at<uchar>(i,j) == 255)
     {
       // Error shown here
       cloud.points[i][j].getVector3fMap() = &points[num_valid_points];
       num_valid_points++;

      }


}
```

The error shown is : 
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka pcl::PointXYZI}’ and ‘int’)

Comment: Is "in_ThreeD_cloud" an organized cloud? Make the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749230/6812182 could assist you.

Comment: If yes: access your cloud with `cloud.at(i,j).getVector3fMap()` (cloud.points is an std::vector)

Comment: in_ThreeD_cloud is not an organized cloud

Comment: are the points in  in_ThreeD_cloud ordered in row and column format?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue is in your point cloud access call.  You need to use comma notation instead of a second brackets and I also believe (correct me if I am wrong) that the coordinates need to be in col, row order. *instead of your [row][col] order.

I also changed your cloud to xyz since you are not inserting any intensity into it (but rather just checking the image to determine existence of a point).

Finally, make sure that you know the order (row vs col) that points are stored in your 3d cloud and make sure you loop through in the same fashion.

```
// An object to class PointCloud is created
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud; 

// Image data from the camera is accessed as Matrix
cv::Mat image  = rrlib::coviroa::AccessImageAsMat(in_img->at(0));

// Dimensions of the point cloud is sent as parameters to overloaded constuctor
cloud(image.cols, image.rows); 

// The point cloud is expected to store the vector3f data in a 2D format
for(int i = 0; i <= image.rows; ++i)
for(int j = 0; j <= image.cols; ++j)
{
     if( image.at<uchar>(i,j) == 255)
     {
       // Error shown here
       cloud.points[j,i].getVector3fMap() = &points[num_valid_points];
       num_valid_points++;

      }
}
```