# How to organize an unorganized Point Cloud of Velodyne HL-32

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I was wondering if it is possible to organize an unorganized point cloud given by the Velodyne HDL-32E. I guess it is applicable to any kind of point cloud, not only given by the Velodyne. To take the point cloud I use PCL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should solve your question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731101/generate-image-from-an-unorganized-point-cloud-in-pcl)